# What does <==> in an LDAP query mean?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am currently looking into some nasty LDAP queries, I have found from schema.msc that "member" is not indexed.

I can see member mentioned in the following query:

```
member <==>CN=aa@bbb.cc, OU=Test, DC=Extern, DC=Intern
```

Which results in an insane amounts of visits and <10% returned entries.

Should i index member to improve this behaviour?
and what does the `<==>` notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should index any attribute that is used in a filter.
2. It doesn't mean anything according to [RFC 4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515) but it can't sensibly mean anything else but 'equals'.